# how to assign ipv6 addresses to an interface behand a netfilter firewall

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, router, ipv6

I need some advice on how to configure my system so that it can assign some of the /64 bock of ipv6 addresses provided by our ISP to devices which are behind a netfiler (iptables) firewall.

Our ISP router assigns ipv6 addresses correctly, and it correctly assigns a global unicast address to eth0, which is an interface on a separate Ubuntu box that is connected to it via ethernet. That box also contains eth1, an interface to which all our devices are connected. All works fine for ipv4 - I can use NAT in iptables to direct traffic from the network on eth0 (192.168.1.0/24) to the network on eth1 (10.0.0.0/24). But I don't want to use NAT in ipv6 - I want our ISP router to be able to assign global unicast addresses to the devices on the eth1 interface, and at the same time I want to use iptables to filter traffic between eth0 and eth1.

Is this going to be possible, and if so how?

EDIT
Have been asked in the comments to provide a network diagram:
[image: networkdiagram]

Comment: You should use the IPv6 Prefix Delegation provided by the ISP to assign the `/64` prefixes to the various networks on your site.

Comment: I think that that is what I don't know how to do with respect to the eth1 interface. For the eth0 interface, our ISP router does it automatically.

Comment: Your router is configured to accept the prefix delegation to assign to your various networks, then you assign the subnet portion and the prefixes get automatically prepended to the subnets to create the various `/64` networks.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you say, I just don't know how to do it. eth1 is not plugged into our ISP router - how do I get our ISP router to assign what it necessary to the devices plugged into eth1?

Comment: No, the ISP router delegates to your router, and your router does the assignments.

Comment: Yes, again I can see what you say, but do not know how to implement it. Do you have a link to something I can read please?

Comment: That depends on the router model. For example, [Cisco has a lot of documents for this](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-version-6-ipv6/113141-DHCPv6-00.html).

Comment: Okay, that's on the ISP router side - the network diagram is a little different in my case, as in the diagram both Client1 and Client2 are connected to the DHCPclient, whereas in my case Client2 is connected to Client1 and not to the DHCPclient.

Comment: You still have not even said what model of router you have! Nobody can give you router-specific help unless you say what router you use.

Comment: There are two routers - an Ubuntu box with eth0 and eth1 in it using iptables to direct traffic between them, and our ISP's router.

Comment: A network diagram is also helpful in understanding the situation.

Comment: Okay, I'll try and produce one and add it to the question.

Comment: Network diagram added.